# MQTTnet : Unable to connect With TLS : Interop+AppleCrypto+SslException: bad protocol version

Tags: .net-core, mqttnet

I am a new .NET core user trying to learn how to connect a managed client with TLS on MacOS Catalina, using [MQTTnet](https://github.com/chkr1011/MQTTnet).

I am trying to connect from ASP.NET Core 3 Background Service to a Mosquitto broker. Using [MqttExplorer](https://mqtt-explorer.com/) I am able to connect successfully to the server over TLS, with username, password and a server certificate (CA) file. So, I know the Mosquitto Broker is configured correctly.

However, I am unable to achieve this with MQTTnet.

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(_Config.Tls.CACerts, FileMode.Open))
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream((int)fileStream.Length))
                {
                    fileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);

                    _Logger.LogInformation($"Read file stream with length {memoryStream.Length} bytes, trying to connect with options:");
                    _Logger.LogInformation($"mqtt://{_Config.UserName}:{_Config.Password}/{_Config.Host}:{_Config.Port}");

                    _MqttOptions = new ManagedMqttClientOptionsBuilder()
                        .WithAutoReconnectDelay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
                        .WithClientOptions(new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
                            .WithClientId(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                            .WithCredentials(_Config.UserName, _Config.Password)
                            .WithTcpServer(_Config.Host, _Config.Port)
                            .WithTls(
                                o =>
                                {
                                    o.UseTls = true;
                                    o.AllowUntrustedCertificates = true;
                                    o.SslProtocol = SslProtocols.Tls12;
#if WINDOWS_UWP
                                    o.Certificates = new List<byte[]>
                                    {
                                        new X509Certificate(memoryStream.ToArray()).Export(X509ContentType.Cert)
                                    };
#else
                                    o.Certificates = new List<X509Certificate>
                                    {
                                        new X509Certificate(memoryStream.ToArray())
                                    };
#endif

                                    o.CertificateValidationHandler = (context) =>
                                    {
                                        _Logger.LogInformation($"SSL POLICY ERRORS {context.SslPolicyErrors.ToString()}");
                                        return true;
                                    };
                                }
                            )
                            .Build())
                        .Build();
                }
```

I receive the following exception:

```sh
MQTTnet.Exceptions.MqttCommunicationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception.
 ---> Interop+AppleCrypto+SslException: bad protocol version
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ThrowIfExceptional()
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsClientAsync>b__64_2(IAsyncResult iar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at MQTTnet.Implementations.MqttTcpChannel.ConnectAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MQTTnet.Implementations.MqttTcpChannel.ConnectAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MQTTnet.Internal.MqttTaskTimeout.WaitAsync(Func`2 action, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MQTTnet.Adapter.MqttChannelAdapter.ConnectAsync(TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MQTTnet.Adapter.MqttChannelAdapter.WrapException(Exception exception)
   at MQTTnet.Adapter.MqttChannelAdapter.ConnectAsync(TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MQTTnet.Client.MqttClient.ConnectAsync(IMqttClientOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>> [2020-10-02T16:07:03.9254330Z] [4] [MqttClient] [Verbose]: Disconnecting [Timeout=00:00:10]
>> [2020-10-02T16:07:03.9255750Z] [4] [MqttClient] [Verbose]: Disconnected from adapter.
>> [2020-10-02T16:07:03.9256240Z] [4] [MqttClient] [Info]: Disconnected.
```

Also, explictly tried adding `WithProtocolVersion(MQTTnet.Formatter.MqttProtocolVersion.V311)` to client options builder.

Is anyone able to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get it working!

The problem was that the mosquitto broker was configured to use Tls v1.3 only. However, with dotnet core 3.1 tls1.3 does not appear to be supported on macOS environments? It is available on Linux environments if openssl 1.1.1 is available.

I have downgraded the mosquitto broker configuration to use tls version 1.2 and the code above now connects.

If anyone has managed to get a dotnet core 3.1 client connecting to mosquitto broker using tlsv1.3 then any details would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[There is similar very issue on github](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27132)

[As a workaround one user proposed following cli command:](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27132#issuecomment-419232421)

```
dotnet dev-certs https
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

**A bit of docs about them.**

[Trust the ASP.NET Core HTTPS development certificate on Windows and macOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#trust-the-aspnet-core-https-development-certificate-on-windows-and-macos)

> Installing the .NET Core SDK installs the ASP.NET Core HTTPS
> development certificate to the local user certificate store. The
> certificate has been installed, but it's not trusted. To trust the
> certificate, perform the one-time step to run the dotnet dev-certs
> tool:

Comment: Hi, Thanks for response, appreciated :) I am not using a dotnet development certificate. I am using a CA certificate from my MQTT Broker, generated using OpenSSL. The CA certificate is working because I can connect to the MQTTBroker with it using MQTTExplorer

Answer (score 0):

Landed here through Google because I had the following error when debugging locally (Angular and .NET 6 web api)

System.IO.IOException: The decryption operation failed, see inner exception.
---> Interop+AppleCrypto+SslException: misc. bad certificate

I tried

```
dotnet dev-certs https
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

but no luck.

What helped in the end was going to the URL of my local running api in the browser, I got a "Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead" message. After clicking Advanced -> Accept the risk and continue, my call succeeded.